# Excel - how to retain divide and multiply functions displaying individually in a cell, based on an input in other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is a tricky one. I was not able to find a solution to this and need your help! Please refer to the attached screenshot.

Explanation:

Cells B2,B3,B4 have random numbers. In cell B6 I have a result from dividing each number(or all numbers) by a random number (in this specific case 52). In cell A9 I have another number input which I would like to multiply by the result in cell B6. My question is: is there a way to retain the result, and not break the formula in B6 when dividing the random numbers in B2-4, when the value in column A9 is 0 or blank? And at the same time to display the result from B2/52*A9 (if we have a value of 1+ in A9)? I hope this makes sense.

[image]

Comment: sounds lke a simple case of using the `if` function

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, but like gns100 suggested.  Maybe your formula could be =IFERROR(YFORMULA of Interest,0)

Answer (score 1):

If, as suggested in the Comments to your post, you want a single value like the "2" shown in B6, a simple `IF` is indeed the answer. And your inactivity on the Comments suggests they understand your post better than I do.

When I read it, I get the impression you want the result of all the calculations, but want them for the entire set of values in your input range, B2:B4 in this case. So you want something like:

```
31, 6, 111
```

or

```
26, 0, 117
```

in B6. If so, then the first can be done like so:

```
=IF(A9<1,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ROUND(B2:B4/52,0)),TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ROUND((B2:B4/52)*$A$9,0)))
```

and the second can be done by:

```
=IF(A9<1,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ROUND(B2:B4/52,0)),TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ROUND((B2:B4/52),0)*$A$9))
```

(The difference being where the multiplication by A9 occurs:  inside the `ROUND` function so it is multiplied by a decimal containing value, or outside the `ROUND` function so it multiplies an integer, always.)

And if not what you wanted, it still illustrates... something... and might be of interest to someone. Also, it too is simply a straightforward `IF` with some hijinks in the creation of its outputs.

Comment: Thank you much! This solves it.